# Select database rows using relations and connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to select some data from the database using Laravel's Eloquent class for my model.

I have tried the following in order to change the database connection used to the `test`-connection: `$users = Users::on('test')->with('posts')->get();`

My database connections are the following: (Note: the only difference is the table prefix `(prefix)`)

```
    'default' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'test' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'test_',
    ),
```

The problem is that when running the above code (`$users = Users::on('test')->with('posts')->get();`) then it runs the following SQL:

```
select * from `test_users`
select `posts`.*, `users_posts`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `users_posts`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id` from `posts` inner join `users_posts` on `posts`.`id` = `users_posts`.`post_id` where `users_posts`.`post_id` in ('1', '2', '3')
```

In the results there are no `posts`, due to that it takes `posts` from the table `posts` instead of `test_posts`, and so on for `users_posts`.

The method for getting users posts in the user model is the following:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Users', 'users_posts', 'user_id', 'post_id');
}
```

Is this a bug or how can I get this to work for me? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need the additional database for unit testing purposes or is it just an additional db you need for your application?

Comment: Where did you get `*::on('test')` from? Try `DB::connection('test')->table(*)->*`, that worked for me.

Comment: @Bogdan, its for the actual database which is needed in my application.

Comment: @SaintGenius, according to the docs on Eloquent it says that I can use `$user = User::on('connection-name')->find(1);`. The informations on this is in the bottom of the [**Basic Usage**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) section. Also I prefer using models instead of the direct DB object methods.

Comment: Well, in that case you should just tell your raw query that you want to use test_posts. Because it don't know nothing about the prefix ;)

Comment: @SaintGenius, the problem is that I runtime change the connection due to the usage of the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [**pull request**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6582) on [**Laravel/Framework**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/) which makes it possible to set the connection behavior of Model Relations.

I integrated this into my package and it worked.

The author gives some examples of usage:

### Examples

#### Application configs: `database.php`

```
return [
    'default' => 'conn1',

    'connections' => [
        'conn1' => [ ****** ], 
        'conn2' => [ ****** ]
    ]
];
```

#### Parent Model

```
class Parent extends Eloquent
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Child', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

#### Behavior Before:

```
Parent::with('children')->get();
// model Parent $connection = 'conn1';
// model Child $connection = 'conn1';


Parent::on('conn2')->with('children')->get();
// model Parent $connection = 'conn2';
// model Child $connection = 'conn1'; (default connection)
```

#### After fix:

```
Parent::with('children')->get();
// model Parent $connection = 'conn1';
// model Child $connection = 'conn1';

Parent::on('conn2')->with('children')->get();
// model Parent $connection = 'conn2';
// model Child $connection = 'conn1';  (default connection)

Parent::on('conn2', true)->with('children')->get();
// model Parent $connection = 'conn2';
// model Child $connection = 'conn2'; (connection of parent model)
```

Comment: The only thing, I really wish it could be done without extending this much. Cause whenever Eloquent/Model is updated, I have to update the package that I'm working on.